# What does Worf say in Klingon in the TNG episode "All Good Things"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, worf, klingon-language

I was rewatching "All Good Things" from *ST:TNG*.  In the scene when the Klingons attack the *USS Pasteur*, Captain (Beverly) Picard tells Worf to signal their surrender.

Worf replies with

> Tos Vah'cha Worf, do'lo jegh!
>   <sub>[transcript on Chakoteya.net](http://www.chakoteya.net/NextGen/277.htm)</sub>

Apparently the Klingon translators I found online don't seem to be able to translate this line.  Can someone tell me what this means?

Comment: http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/277.txt has it as "This is Governor Worf, we surrender!"

Comment: @SQB - And you've not posted that as an answer because.....?

Comment: @Valorum because I don't speak Klingon and can't verify it. Also, translating that phrase back to Klingon using various online translators didn't come close except for "jegh" having something to do with "surrender".

Comment: @SQB - The script is always the right answer, even if it conflicts with the Klingon language invented by Mark Okrand

Comment: It wasn't unusual for screenwriters or actors to have "Klingon" in the show that didn't actually make sense, even after Okrand published the "official" dictionary. The Klingon Dictionary itself makes note of this.

Comment: Not only was it not unusual for the screenwriters to ignore the Klingon language; it was the standard. This is no exception.

Comment: Please don't add comments as edits. You can comment here below if you want to communicate with the person who made the changes...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [original screenplay](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/277.txt) identifies it thusly.

> [Worf works a console for a moment.]
>
> **WORF:** (to com) *Tos Vah'cha Worf, do'lo jegh!*
> **(This is Governor Worf, we surrender!)**

Comment: For the curious: To say this in tlhIngan Hol, the Klingon language created by Marc Okrand, you might say something like **wo'rIv qumwI' jIH! majegh!**

Answer (score 1):

According to a [Klingon dictionary](http://klingonska.org/dict/) the words from your transcript excerpt translate as follows:

- toS = climb
- vaH = holster, sheath, knife case
- cha = torpedoes
- Worf = Worf
- Do = velocity, speed
- lo = ?
- jegh = surrender, give up

So, yeah. I'm no expert in klingon grammar and it looks a bit like gibberish to me. But maybe someone can figure out the rest from here.

Comment: Note that in Standard Klingon (which the quote isn't), *vaH'cha* and *Do'lo* would be one word each, not two. The apostrophe is a letter in its own right in Klingon, not punctuation. So the translation into *vaH*, *cha*, *Do*, and *lo* is inapt either way.